# application.cfc is adding a space at the end of .ics files

Tags: ios, coldfusion, icalendar, application.cfc

Edit: I was able to solve it, but not sure it is very elegant.

Originally, I was building the ICS content (calCreated), then outputing that after a cfheader and cfcontent tag. Here is what I came up with:

`<cfset tempFile = getTempDirectory() & 'cal.ics'>`
`<cffile action="write"  file="#tempFile#"  output="#calCreated#" fixnewline="No">`
`<cffile action="readBinary"  file="#tempFile#" variable="calBinary">`
`<cfcontent type="text/calendar" reset="Yes" variable="#calBinary#">`
`<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=CalendarItem.ics">`

The only oddity is, as you can see, I have the filename specified, but it uploads calendarcreator.ics (the script file is calendarcreator.cfm) instead of the specified name.

Thanks for the responses and I would welcome any thoughts on the code.

Original post:
I have a script that creates a .ics file, which worked fine until I moved to application.cfc, which adds a character to the end of the file. With that extra space, IOS will not recognize the file and won't open it.

I welcome any thoughts on how I can eliminate that space or on getting IOS to recognize the file.

I changed the output for the onRequest function in application.cfc to void, but it still adds that extra character.

Comment: I recommend providing some code for people to review in order to get help with your issue.

Comment: It's impossible to comment sensibly on this with seeing some code that reproduces the issue. From your comment below though, you're using tag-based code in your Application.cfc file, which won't be helping. Limit tag usage to views. Use script-based code everywhere else. Voting to close as the question lacks sufficient substance to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think both ACF and Lucee have whitespace auto-trimming options - Lucee, for sure.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but any scripting after the cfoutput, including the ```</cfif>``` I originally had in the code and now the ```</cffunction>```, was causing that extra character. It seemed to be a return character, but I couldn't figure out what IOS didn't like about it.

Comment: I presume you've already tried this:  https://cfdocs.org/cfprocessingdirective

If you can't find a resolution to this problem, you might consider writing a trimmed ics file to a ram drive and then delivering it via cfcontent rather than direct output as a workaround.

I also encourage you to look into cfscript vs tags, and consider a framework like https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/for-newbies/60-minute-quick-start.  Using cfscript, you can build the structure you're looking for, trim() it, and then use echo() or writeOutput() to dump the results into the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

What is the character-encoding of calCreated? I ask because, with `<cffile action="write"  file="#tempFile#"  output="#calCreated#" fixnewline="No">` you are apparently writing text content to file. However, you are then reading it back as binary. Just a thought.
In any case, here's what I think might solve the problem: use the attribute `output="false"` for the functions onRequestStart and onRequest and for any other functions involved in generating the content.